Express.js - Route called twice because of CORS
I have the following Node.js code:
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

// Enable CORS
const origin = [];

origin.push(
  /http:\/\/localhost:.*/,
  /https:\/\/localhost:.*/,
  /http:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1:.*/,
  /https:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1:.*/
);

app.use(
  cors({
    origin,
    credentials: true
  })
);

app.put('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('PUT REQUEST');
  res.status(200).json({});
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 5000');
});

When I call the route from Angular:
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.http.put('http://localhost:5000', {}).subscribe();
}

I get this in my Node.js console:
PUT REQUEST
PUT REQUEST

The route is called twice when CORS is enabled. It doesn't happen when CORS is disabled:
// const origin = [];

// origin.push(
//   /http:\/\/localhost:.*/,
//   /https:\/\/localhost:.*/,
//   /http:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1:.*/,
//   /https:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1:.*/
// );

// app.use(
//  cors({
//    origin,
//    credentials: true
//  })
// );

The output without CORS is:
PUT REQUEST

Does somebody have an explanation/solution?
Note: I also tried to call the route from a React front and it runs properly. It looks like an issue with CORS and Angular.

can't reproduce, runs normally. what's your environment/node/ng version

@traynor Node: v20.10.0. Angular: 17.3.0

options shouldn't trigger route.. can you add request logger middleware: app.use((req, res, next)=>{  console.log(req.headers, req.method, req.url);  next(); });, and see how many requests are coming, also, in angular, you could try making request with fetch, and maybe change and mix options for both
